# Access Navigation settings error occured

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, error, navigation, settings

I have a problem accessing the Navigation settings, and the left navigation bar no longer exists.
When it happened, I was organizing this navigation bar and adding a new sub-site template. I also deleted a sub-site, but the top bar is functional and I can still access these Parameters.

When I try to Access to the Navigation Settings, a error page opens "an error occurered..."

"Das hat leider nicht geklappt. 
Es ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten. 
Technische Details

Führen Sie die Problembehandlung mit Microsoft SharePoint Foundation aus. 
Korrelations-ID: f372659e-6290-e083-6033-ff532bfcde0c"

Please be very precise in your answer, I am working with SharePoint in german, but I am French... Sometimes complicated to find my in the Settings.

I have the owner permission.
I don't have Access to SharePoint designer, the command line...

I'd like to know how to solve this Problem

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's never so complicated, I deleted the lists, documents, or whatever... I knew that it would be in my bin so I had no worries. And everything back to normal. My left Navigation bar is here, and I can Access to the Navigation Settings.